What determines I2C interrupt service time after address byte ACK?
I am looking at the NXP spec for I2C and what I don't understand is the timing constraint for the portion of the transmission where the "clock line held LOW while interrupts are serviced" (see the timing diagram below). A lot of the I2C transmissions I have captured (specially in fast mode plus) have a small 2µs pause between that 9th ack bit and the start of the data bit. I can't seem to find where there is a constraint on this OR whether this can be controlled in the master. For reference, I am using an STM32L4 series MCU.


It is defined by what the MCU was doing when byte is transferred, how long it takes to notice I2C interface needs servicing, and how quickly the I2C interface is serviced and ready for next transfer. It is possible interrupts have nothing to do with it, or if they do, then it may be th MCU was already serving another interrupt or other critical task so I2C gets handled when previous critical section is done.
Basically, nothing defines it except how your code happens to work and how long it takes your code to do it.
Also it depends if the STM32 you use is the master or slave on the bus. You also have three different methods, polled, interrupts and DMA.
When the master wants to transfer, any time the slave is not ready, it is allowed to stretch the clock at any time, it does not need to do it per byte but can do per bit. Also the master can send at any rate it wants, if you want to have intetional delays between bytes it is also fine.
If you want a simpler example, maybe datasheet examples how some simpler MCU like AVR must work with I2C.

I will take a look at AVR for a more detailed datasheet. Thank you! I think this answered my question, it's not a concern as long as the rest of the I2C SI is within spec and the communication between master and slave work as expected.
